# Easiest way to establish data communication from Android to a Eclipse program with WLAN

Tags: java, android, exchange-server, wifi

Now, I have some problems here:

I looked several times in Google and so on, but I can't find an "easy" way to get this done. And currently having a migraine... not helping me... though

I have a java eclipse program (Swing application to be a "controller" for production-machines).

I need to design an Android app, which needs to take data  from the eclipse program in a wireless network (and also send them back).

Just found solutions like JPARSON or setting up a real server, but that is way too complicated... i don´t need?! (or want :D ) to set up a whole website with php or something...

Can someone of you help me out with a better solution? It doesn't need to be code-specific, I just want to exchange like 10 strings for these machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exchange data you need a communication medium. The easiest way to do this is via TCP/IP protocol suite. If you decide on having a Server-Client architecture, your serwer has to listen for what phones have to say. He can do this by listening on specified port and you would have to handle "protocol", or you can use somewhat easier approach which is to write php script, or Java Servlet. PHP script is easier becaouse there is like a gazzilion php hosting providers and it's cheap. If you would like to write your own serwer, you wold need some sort of Virtual Private Server, and deploy your app there. Plus it would be helpfull if you explained a little more your environment and what you are trying to achive.

Comment: With TCP/IP, can i exchange via a local textfile or something? It has not to be professional, and i doubt it´s worth the time to make it "big"

I have a simulation running, on my eclipse and lets say 10 machines. They have a few details, like status or estimated finish-time. With my android App, i have to visualize the information of the 10 machines (or less if less selected) and add details or something. 

I think with php or a VPS it would be way to much effort, it´s just about the communication, with one specific mobile phone to my eclipse program.

Did i make myself more specific? :)

Answer (score 1):

There's built in httpserver http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/index.html  so you can easily implement a simple webservice in standalone java. Then just use URLConnection from android to post/get data, probably in json or your own format.

Comment: Oh jeah it was JSON , mistaken that one :D

Would it be possible to use JSON for a local file on the pc where my eclipse program is running? So that i don´t have to implement the server (or is their no way getting around :( )

Comment: not quite got what you meant there, how will you use the file?